# how to use enums in spring data @Query

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use a static value retrieved from an enum as a parameter in a `@Query` definition in spring data, but the SpEL seems not to be resolved correctly:

```
@Query("SELECT o from AType o WHERE o.id = :id AND o.enumType = ?#{T(com.comap.EnumType).MY_TYPE.getId()}")
Participant findTypedById(@Param("id") Long vacancyId);
```

`com.comap.EnumType.MY_TYPE.getId()` returns `2`

but the exception I get is this:

```
Not all named parameters have been set: [1] [SELECT o from AType o WHERE o.id = :id AND o.enumType = ?1]
```

If I change the SpEL prefix to `:#`, like this:

```
@Query("SELECT o from AType o WHERE o.id = :id AND o.enumType = :#{T(com.comapny.EnumType).MY_TYPE.getId()}")
Participant findTypedById(@Param("id") Long vacancyId);
```

Then I get this error:

```
Not all named parameters have been set: [__$synthetic$__1] [SELECT o from AType o WHERE o.id = :id AND o.enumType = :__$synthetic$__1]
```

What am I doing wrong or is this not supported?

update:

changing the prefix to only `#` causes this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '#' [SELECT o from AType o WHERE o.id = :id AND o.enumType = #{T(com.comapny.EnumType).MY_TYPE.getId()}]
```

Comment: what happens if you execute :
`@Query("SELECT o from AType o WHERE o.id = :?1 AND o.enumType = #{T(com.comap.EnumType).MY_TYPE.getId()}")`

Comment: @NikolayRusev I added an update to answer your question

Comment: Why don't you change the Query to: `@Query("SELECT o from AType o WHERE o.id = :id AND o.enumType = :enumTypeId")` and call this method like this: `findTypedById(id, EnumType.MY_TYPE.getId());` ?

Comment: because we only need a method to return items of the exact type. Adding the enum as a parameter will allow access to other items too and makes the interface error-prone as always the same type would need to be passed.